# Reading/writing yahoo calendar (beta) in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, yahoo, caldav

Is there any way to access the yahoo calendar (beta) events in asp.net code behind file? i want to access the user calendar events with OAuth or with username/password combination. Yahoo only describes that it supports CalDav but how to do it in .net and with what caldav library.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing...been struggling to find examples or documentation on how to do this.  The only helpful thing I've found so far is if you enter the URL of the yahoo caldav calendar in a browser, you seem to get a CalDav response.